# 'Best' location of a matplotlib table not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encountered a problem with the 'best' location for matplotlib tables. Consider the following code below, with the following output [here](https://s15.postimg.org/b4zknk9ej/matplotlib_table.png). It can be observed that the location is not the best, despite specifying for the 'best' location possible. Is there any way to improve the table location? As much as possible, I do not want to place it outside the plot area.

EDIT: I am discouraged to use specific location (loc='bottom' or bbox=(x,y,w,h)) since my actual data are random.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,11)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)

# generate table
col_labels = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
row_labels = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
table_vals = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33,]]

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                     colWidths=[0.1] * len(col_labels),
                     rowLabels=row_labels,
                     colLabels=col_labels,
                     loc='best')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems `loc='best'` is not really the best position in this case.

The easiest solution here might be to use `loc=4`,

```
plt.table(... , loc=4)
```

More generally, you can use any of the [position keys](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) supported by `plt.legend()`, which are numbers from `0` to `9` or strings like `"upper right"` or `"lower left"`

Also, you can specify a bounding box as a four-tuple `bbox=(x0,y0,width,height)`, where `x0` and `y0` are the coordinates relative the the axes of the lower left edge of the inner table. In this case try e.g.

```
plt.table(... , bbox=(0.2,0.6,0.2,0.2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, I avoid using a specific location, since my data are random. The above case is just an example of the loc='best' not working.

Comment: In that case you have only two options: Place the table outside the axes, or develop your own algorithm for finding the best location.

Comment: Or try to understand [what 'best' is exactly](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/table.py), and maybe fix it. I've been giving it a look out of curiosity, but it is a bit obscure.

Comment: It's not actually that obscure. Seen from the sourceode, it just places the table in the upper right corner. One could also say it's simply ignored. One would need to implement something similar to the [best location in axes.legend](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/legend.py#L893)